# How to dynamically create a variable with the data type of table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the following query select_string can return any number of columns and rows with any possible data types.

```
Execute immediate 'select_string' into v_table_variable;
```

For example select_string could be `'select name, last name from student'` or `'select date, subject, address , phone from booking'` and so on.

Does anyone has any idea how I can define the v_table_variable so that the execute immediate is run as I want?! I intend to make a loop afterwards to read the values from this variable.

Many thanks!

Comment: You realistically probably can't.  You might be able to dynamically build an entire PL/SQL block (including the subsequent loop) but resorting to dynamic PL/SQL is generally a quick way to drive yourself (and anyone that has to maintain your code) insane.  It's possible that you want to use `dbms_sql` rather than `execute immediate` but it's pretty rare that you'd really want to write code that is that generic.  What is the underlying problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!  I want to build a function to get the name of a table and a value which is one of its PK and then delete all corresponding rows in the child tables, and in the child of the child and so on.  I am not allowed to alter my tables with the cascade .

Comment: Are you sure that you really need a completely generic function?  Rather than, say, a `delete_foo` procedure that deletes a `foo` by first deleting data from all the tables that are children of `foo`?  You could build a single procedure that read from a bunch of data dictionary tables and created a bunch of dynamic SQL.  But that's an order of magnitude more complex than a simple, procedural option.  Are you sure that the additional complexity is really worth it?

Comment: So you have some tables with foreign key constraints but without `ON DELETE CASCADE` and you want to "simulate" the cascade in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "full blown" dynmamic version would be this one (not tested):

```
DECLARE  
  v_stmt_str       VARCHAR2(200);
  v_cur            INTEGER;
  v_rows_processed INTEGER;

  col_cnt     INTEGER;
  rec_tab     DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  rec         DBMS_SQL.DESC_REC;

  num_var NUMBER;
  string_var VARCHAR2(4000);
  date_var DATE;
  -- .. some more variables if needed 
BEGIN
  v_cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR; -- open cursor 
  v_stmt_str := 'SELECT whatever from ....';
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(v_cur, v_stmt_str, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE); 
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(v_cur, col_cnt, rec_tab);  

  FOR c in 1..col_cnt LOOP
     rec := rec_tab(c);
     IF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
         DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_cur, c, num_var); 
     ELSIF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
         DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_cur, c, string_var, rec.col_max_len); 
     ELSIF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
         DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(v_cur, c, date_var); 
     -- .. some more data types if needed
     END IF;
  END LOOP;

  -- Execute
  v_rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(v_cur);  
  LOOP 
    -- Fetch a row 
    IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(v_cur) > 0 THEN 
      FOR c in 1..col_cnt LOOP
        rec := rec_tab(c);
        IF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(v_cur, c, num_var); 
        ELSIF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(v_cur, c, string_var); 
        ELSIF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(v_cur, c, date_var); 
        -- .. some more data types if needed
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      -- Process: do something with num_var or string_var or date_var values
    ELSE
      EXIT; 
    END IF; 
  END LOOP; 
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_cur); -- close cursor
END;
/
```

But as already stated in comments, check your requirements if you really need it such dynamic - probably not.

Check Oracle documentation [Coding Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dynamic_sql.htm) and [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm) for other examples. There are various methods providing different "levels" of dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for your great tip :-). I was not familiar with DBMS_SQL. Just one thing, shouldn't "do something with num_var or ..." Be before the latest end loop ?! If our query returns for example 4 columns with data type number, then I guess, in this way we would have just the last value in num_var, right?!   Just want to make sure I have got it right. This was a great help to me, thank you so much :-)

Comment: YEs, if your table contains several `NUMBER` type column you have to process them inside the loop. Or you can put them into a nested table and process the nested table after the loop.