# Oracle Dynamic PL/SQL from table

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, record

Trying to run some dynamic sql to check validations. These validations will be some pattern to check against, stored in a table.

```
DECLARE
  in_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_TABLE';

  l_table_record VARCHAR2(30) := in_table_name || '_r';
  l_table_table VARCHAR2(30) := in_table_name || '_t';
  l_table_list VARCHAR2(30) := in_table_name || '_l';

  TYPE validation_cols_r IS RECORD (COLUMN_NAME COLUMNS_TO_VALIDATE.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE,
                                    VALIDATION_TYPE COLUMNS_TO_VALIDATE.VALIDATION_TYPE%TYPE,
                                    CUSTOM_SQL COLUMNS_TO_VALIDATE.CUSTOM_SQL%TYPE
                                   );
  TYPE validation_cols_t IS TABLE OF validation_cols_r;
  l_validation_columns validation_cols_t;

  l_first NUMBER := 0; -- Simple boolean flag, always set when using, assume value changes if leaving current block
  l_build_select VARCHAR2(4000) := 'SELECT';
  l_build_record VARCHAR(4000) := 'TYPE ' || l_table_record || ' IS RECORD (';
  l_build_table VARCHAR2(4000) := 'TYPE ' || l_table_table || ' IS TABLE OF ' || l_table_record;
  l_build_list VARCHAR2(4000) := l_table_list || ' ' || l_table_table;

  l_build_main VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN

  SELECT COLUMN_NAME, VALIDATION_TYPE, CUSTOM_SQL
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_validation_columns
  FROM COLUMNS_TO_VALIDATE
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = in_table_name
  ;

  -- Generate the SELECT statement to get all the records
  l_first := 1;
  FOR indx IN 1 .. l_validation_columns.COUNT
  LOOP
    IF (l_first = 1) THEN
      l_build_select := l_build_select || ' ' || l_validation_columns(indx).COLUMN_NAME;
      l_build_record := l_build_record || l_validation_columns(indx).COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || in_table_name || '.' || l_validation_columns(indx).COLUMN_NAME || '%TYPE';
      l_first := 0;
    ELSE
      l_build_select := l_build_select || ', ' || l_validation_columns(indx).COLUMN_NAME;
      l_build_record := l_build_record || ', ' || l_validation_columns(indx).COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || in_table_name || '.' || l_validation_columns(indx).COLUMN_NAME || '%TYPE';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  l_build_select := l_build_select || ' BULK COLLECT INTO ' || l_table_list || ' FROM ' || in_table_name;
  l_build_record := l_build_record || ')';

  FOR vt IN 1 .. l_validation_columns.COUNT
  LOOP
    l_build_main :=
    '
      DECLARE
      ' || l_build_record || ';
      ' || l_build_table || ';
      ' || l_build_list || ';
      BEGIN
        ' || l_build_select || ';

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''Count: '' || ' || l_table_list || '.COUNT);
        FOR rec IN 1 .. ' || l_table_list || '.COUNT
        LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''' || l_validation_columns(vt).COLUMN_NAME || ': '' || ' || l_table_list || '(rec).' || l_validation_columns(vt).COLUMN_NAME || ');
          CASE ''' || l_validation_columns(vt).VALIDATION_TYPE || '''
            WHEN ''RANGE'' THEN
              IF (' || l_table_list || '(rec).' || l_validation_columns(vt).COLUMN_NAME || ' NOT BETWEEN ' || l_validation_columns(vt).CUSTOM_SQL || ')
              THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''Fails range validation'');
              END IF;
            ELSE
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''No type of validation'');
          END CASE;

        END LOOP;
      END;
    ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_build_main;
--    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_build_main);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This produces the error:

> Error report -
>   ORA-06550: line 16, column 47:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:
>      in like like2 like4 likec between member submultiset
>   ORA-06550: line 26, column 4:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>      ;  
>   The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
>   ORA-06512: at line 81
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

When I output the dynamic sql using DBMS_OUTPUT and then run it manually it works correctly.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE TEST_TABLE_r IS RECORD (EMAIL TEST_TABLE.EMAIL%TYPE, GENDER TEST_TABLE.GENDER%TYPE, NAME TEST_TABLE.NAME%TYPE, PID TEST_TABLE.PID%TYPE);
  TYPE TEST_TABLE_t IS TABLE OF TEST_TABLE_r;
  TEST_TABLE_l TEST_TABLE_t;
BEGIN
  SELECT EMAIL, GENDER, NAME, PID BULK COLLECT INTO TEST_TABLE_l FROM TEST_TABLE;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Count: ' || TEST_TABLE_l.COUNT);
  FOR rec IN 1 .. TEST_TABLE_l.COUNT
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PID: ' || TEST_TABLE_l(rec).PID);
    CASE 'RANGE'
      WHEN 'RANGE' THEN
        IF (TEST_TABLE_l(rec).PID NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 699)
        THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Fails range validation');
        END IF;
      ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No type of validation');
    END CASE;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

The issue seems to be the line

> IF (' || l_table_list || '(rec).' || l_validation_columns(vt).COLUMN_NAME || ' NOT ' || l_validation_columns(vt).CUSTOM_SQL || ')

Which correctly becomes

> IF (TEST_TABLE_l(rec).PID NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 699)

I'm not sure if at the time of execution the value from the table is not being translated correctly or what. It does work correctly when putting "0 AND 699" in directly.

Any insight would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that when building the dynamic sql

> l_validation_columns(vt).CUSTOM_SQL

would occasionally be null.
This caused that line to come out looking like

```
IF (TEST_TABLE_l(rec).PID NOT BETWEEN )
```

Which is obviously malformed pl/sql.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a smart way of doing. There are different levels dynamic SQL.

If you know the column types at design time then I would suggest a RefCursor like this:

```
declare
   cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
   a VARCHAR2(100);
   b VARCHAR2(100);
   c INTEGER;
begin
   OPEN cur FOR 
      'SELECT EMAIL, NAME, PID FROM TEST_TABLE'; -- or any other dynamic string
   LOOP
      FETCH cur INTO a, b, c;
      EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
      -- do something with a,b,c
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE cur;
END;
```

Of course you can also use BULK FETCH.

If you don't know the column type at design time then you need little more code. Check this answer: [How to dynamically create a variable with the data type of table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305406/how-to-dynamically-create-a-variable-with-the-data-type-of-table/26306647#26306647)

Comment: I won't know how many columns or what types ahead of time, also needs to work on multiple tables.Any additional insight is always welcome