# How to write Execute immediate in cursor select Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to wite EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in the cursor select Query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE biq_attendee_report (in_from_date IN DATE)
IS
   l_cur_query          VARCHAR2 (5000) := 'SELECT * from table X where c1='|| in_from_date;

   CURSOR cur_attendee_data
   IS
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  l_cur_query;

   TYPE rec_attendee_data IS TABLE OF cur_attendee_data%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   l_cur_attendee_data  rec_attendee_data;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur_attendee_data;

   LOOP
      FETCH cur_attendee_data BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_attendee_data;

      EXIT WHEN l_cur_attendee_data.COUNT = 0;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('here in first insert');
      lrec := return_attendee_report ();
      out_attendee_tab :=
         return_attendee_arr_result (return_attendee_report ());
      out_attendee_tab.DELETE;

      FOR i IN 1 .. l_cur_attendee_data.COUNT
      LOOP
         BEGIN
            NULL;
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
               DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error occurred : ' || SQLERRM);
         END;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('HERE INSIIDE OTHERS' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

here I try to use initialize cursor outside begin block but it rises exception, how to write a dynamic query for the cursor,

```
cur_attendee_data is
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  l_cur_query;
```

> Error(113,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CUR_ATTENDEE_DATA" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ;

Comment: From where you are getting `l_date`? Is it `in_from_date`?

Comment: There's nothing dynamic in your code (at least, it doesn't seem so; `l_cur_query` looks wrong; did you post what you really have?); why do you want to use `execute immediate`? Besides, you "forgot" to close the cursor.

Comment: @Littlefoot, If you haven't close the cursor, that will never throw the error.

Comment: @Ankit, cursor, which is opened, has to be closed - if nothing else, because of a good practice. Apart from that, suppose you opened it, never closed it, and then - later in your program - try to open the same cursor again. Then, yes - it will throw an error (ORA-06511: PL/SQL: cursor already open).

Comment: that in_from_date I'm getting as input and appending to query.
and previously I'm using select query for cursor, but now i need to construct query and then need to pass to cursor query

Comment: What is the reason for dynamic query?

Comment: If you don't know the table and column structure at design time then you have to use the `DBMS_SQL` package but it requires more and complex coding, see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305406/how-to-dynamically-create-a-variable-with-the-data-type-of-table/26306647#26306647 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549823/rowtype-variable-from-table-name/26553132#26553132

Answer (score 2):

If you fetch all rows with `BULK COLLECT INTO ...` then you need only one loop, the second loop is useless.

The basic solution would be this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE biq_attendee_report (in_from_date IN DATE) IS

    l_cur_query          VARCHAR2 (5000) := 'SELECT * from {table X} where c1=:d';

   cur_attendee_data SYS_REFCURSOR;    
   TYPE rec_attendee_data IS TABLE OF {table X}%ROWTYPE;
   l_cur_attendee_data  rec_attendee_data;

BEGIN

    OPEN cur_attendee_data FOR l_cur_query USING in_from_date;
    FETCH cur_attendee_data BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_attendee_data;

    FOR i IN 1 .. l_cur_attendee_data.COUNT LOOP
        -- do whatever you like to do with l_cur_attendee_data(i)
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_attendee_data;

END;
```

However, I don't see any reason to make dynamic SQL. You can simply run

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE biq_attendee_report (in_from_date IN DATE) IS    

   cur_attendee_data SYS_REFCURSOR;    
   TYPE rec_attendee_data IS TABLE OF {table X}%ROWTYPE;
   l_cur_attendee_data  rec_attendee_data;

BEGIN

    OPEN cur_attendee_data FOR SELECT * from {table X} where c1 = in_from_date;
    FETCH cur_attendee_data BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_attendee_data;

    FOR i IN 1 .. l_cur_attendee_data.COUNT LOOP
        -- do whatever you like to do with l_cur_attendee_data(i)
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_attendee_data;

END;
```

Comment: in my actual query, I have more that one table

Comment: Do these tables have all the same columns?

Comment: those tables are not having the same columns, Here is my actual query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code instead -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE biq_attendee_report (in_from_date IN DATE)
IS
   l_cur_query          VARCHAR2 (100) := 'SELECT * from table X where c1=:in_from_date';

   TYPE t_cur IS REF CURSOR;
   cur_attendee_data t_cur

   TYPE rec_attendee_data IS TABLE OF cur_attendee_data%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   l_cur_attendee_data  rec_attendee_data;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur_attendee_data FOR l_cur_query USING in_from_date;

   LOOP
      FETCH cur_attendee_data BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_attendee_data;

      EXIT WHEN l_cur_attendee_data.COUNT = 0;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('here in first insert');
      lrec := return_attendee_report ();
      out_attendee_tab :=
         return_attendee_arr_result (return_attendee_report ());
      out_attendee_tab.DELETE;

      FOR i IN 1 .. l_cur_attendee_data.COUNT
      LOOP
         BEGIN
            NULL;
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
               DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error occurred : ' || SQLERRM);
         END;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('HERE INSIIDE OTHERS' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use open cursor for '' as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE biq_attendee_report (in_from_date IN DATE)
IS
   l_cur_query          VARCHAR2 (5000) := 'SELECT * from table X where c1='|| in_from_date;
   cur_attendee_data SYS_REFCURSOR; -- JUST DECLARED THE CURSOR
   --TYPE rec_attendee_data IS TABLE OF cur_attendee_data%ROWTYPE
   --   INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; -- this declaration must be at schema level
   l_cur_attendee_data  rec_attendee_data;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur_attendee_data for l_cur_query; -- OPEN THE CURSOR WITH DYNAMIC QUERY
   ..
   .. -- YOUR CODE AS IT IS
   ..
```

Cheers!!

Comment: where to initialize the type var 
"TYPE rec_attendee_data IS
        TABLE OF cur_attendee_data%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    l_cur_attendee_data   rec_attendee_data;"

Comment: It is really bad to concatenate dynamic SQL with date value. Better use `'SELECT * from table X where c1=:fromDate'; OPEN cur_attendee_data for l_cur_query using in_from_date;`

Comment: Use bind variables and `OPEN cursor_name FOR sql_string USING variable_name`.

Comment: Does not work, you get an `PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed`

Comment: TYPE rec_attendee_data IS
        TABLE OF cur_attendee_data%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    l_cur_attendee_data   rec_attendee_data;
Error(109,18): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed,
do we need any modifications in type decleration..?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, What a perfect guess.

Comment: `TYPE rec_attendee_data IS TABLE OF ` was existing code. I have just concentrated on cursor with dynamic query.

Comment: You cannot define Associative arrays (or index-by table) at schema level.

Comment: Yes, but `CREATE TYPE rec_attendee_data IS TABLE OF NUMBER;` can be done at schema level

Comment: My actual requirement is I need to form an array with the cursor data and have to return is there any alternate solution for this

Comment: when I define type at schema level it through exception like
HERE INSIIDE OTHERSORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -